# Why std::integral auto&& parameter does not work with an lvalue argument

Tags: c++, c++20, auto, c++-concepts, forwarding-reference

I am not sure why the below code doesn't compile:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cwchar>


template <typename T>
concept Character = std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, signed char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, unsigned char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, wchar_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char8_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char16_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char32_t >;

template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto create_character_array( std::integral auto&& fill_character ) noexcept
{
    std::array<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype( fill_character )>, N> dashes { };
    std::fill( std::begin( dashes ), std::end( dashes ), fill_character );

    return dashes;
}

int main( )
{
    const char ch { '^' };
    auto dashes { create_character_array<128>( ch ) };
    dashes.back( ) = '\0';

    std::fputs( std::data( dashes ), stdout );
}
```

I'm not sure but it seems that the universal reference (`auto&&`) and the concept `std::integral` don't work well for some reason. And replacing `std::integral` with my own more precise concept `Character` doesn't help either.

The following error is raised:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:30:46: error: no matching function for call to 'create_character_array<128>(const char&)'
   30 |     auto dashes { create_character_array<128>( ch ) };
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:19:16: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int N, class auto:16>  requires  integral<auto:16> consteval auto create_character_array(auto:16&&)'
   19 | consteval auto create_character_array( std::integral auto&& fill_character ) noexcept
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:19:16: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/compare:37,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/array:38,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<long unsigned int N, class auto:16>  requires  integral<auto:16> consteval auto create_character_array(auto:16&&) [with long unsigned int N = 128; auto:16 = const char&]':
<source>:30:46:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts:100:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'integral<auto:16>' [with auto:16 = const char&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts:100:24: note: the expression 'is_integral_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = const char&]' evaluated to 'false'
  100 |     concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:30:46: error: no matching function for call to 'create_character_array<128>(const char&)'
   30 |     auto dashes { create_character_array<128>( ch ) };
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:19:16: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int N, class auto:16>  requires  integral<auto:16> consteval auto create_character_array(auto:16&&)'
   19 | consteval auto create_character_array( std::integral auto&& fill_character ) noexcept
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:19:16: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/compare:37,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/array:38,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<long unsigned int N, class auto:16>  requires  integral<auto:16> consteval auto create_character_array(auto:16&&) [with long unsigned int N = 128; auto:16 = const char&]':
<source>:30:46:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts:100:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'integral<auto:16>' [with auto:16 = const char&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230509/include/c++/14.0.0/concepts:100:24: note: the expression 'is_integral_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = const char&]' evaluated to 'false'
  100 |     concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It compiles when `'^'` is passed as the argument. However `ch` makes it fail. This happened after adding `std::integral` to the function definition. Without it, the code compiles.

And in case this is not a good design, how should I define the above function to make it as versatile as possible? I want it to accept any value category.

Comment: `auto&&` either becomes `T&` or `T`.  `std::integral` doesn't work with `T&`.  `std::integral auto fill_character` fixes the issue and copying a integral is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition `auto func(std::integral auto&& arg)` is just shorthand for

```
template <typename T>
requires std::integral<T>
auto func(T&& arg)
```

The way forwarding references work is that when you call `func`, `T` will be deduced to either a value type if the argument is an rvalue or a reference type if the argument is an lvalue:

```
func(42);       // T is int, so the type of arg is int&&
func(some_int); // T is int&, so the type of arg is int& &&, which colapses to int&
```

In the latter case, the `std::integral<T>` constraint is unsatisfied, since `int&` is not an integral type.

---

To avoid this issue, either drop the reference (integral types are cheap to copy):

```
template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto create_character_array( std::integral auto fill_character ) noexcept
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0e1bbd58d7b65c5)

Or spell out the requirement long-form and explicitly add a `std::remove_reference_t`:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
requires std::integral<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
consteval auto create_character_array( T&& fill_character ) noexcept
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d43aa672603f3bdb)

Comment: Yes. And I think the first solution is more concise and clear. Also, can we add a const to it? Like `const std::integral auto fill_character`.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  You can think of `std::integral auto` as a standin for `T`.  Anything that can go before or after `T` in the long-form version can go before or after `std::integral auto` in the short-form version.

Answer (score 0):

Final form after fixing the problem:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>


template <typename T>
concept Character = std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, signed char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, unsigned char > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, wchar_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char8_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char16_t > ||
                    std::same_as< std::remove_cv_t<T>, char32_t >;

template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto create_character_array( const Character auto fill_character ) noexcept
{
    std::array<std::remove_const_t<decltype( fill_character )>, N> characters { };
    std::fill( std::begin( characters ), std::end( characters ), fill_character );

    return characters;
}

int main( )
{
    constexpr char dash { '-' };
    auto dashes { create_character_array<128>( dash ) };
    dashes[ 120 ] = '\n';
    dashes[ 121 ] = '\0';

    std::fputs( std::data( dashes ), stdout );
}
```

Comment: Consider using `characters.fill(fill_character);` instead of `std::fill`. Also consider default-initializing `characters` rather than value-initializing it since you immediately overwrite the zeroed contents anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn Does the member `fill()` make any difference? And what about `std::ranges::fill()`?

Comment: It isn't inherently "better", but It obviates the need to include `<algorithm>`, if that's the only reason you're including it